# given and integer, return the next integer that is a prime number and a palindrome . Python

Tags: python

Given any random integer, create a function to find the next number that is a prime number and also a palindrome.

My attempt

```
def golf(number):
    x = number + 1
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0 or str(x) != str(x)[::-1]:
            golf(number + 1)
    return x
```

E.g golf(13) = 101

I'm actually looking for an alternative option than the recursion method i used. How can this best be accomplished without using recursion?

Thanks

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002385

Comment: @alfasin - ...that is also a palindrome.

Comment: And it should be `return golf(number + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Palindrome are a sparser set of numbers than primes, and you can generate palindromes directly.

Consider the sequence 98.102

These are palidrome numbers you can base on these

989, 9889, 999, 9999, 10001, 100001, 10101, 101101, 10201, 102201

ADDED

Not also that all of the palidromes with an odd number of digits will come before the palidromes with an even number of digits.

If you write this as a generator (ie using yield) get get a straightforward algorithm for generating palindromic numbers in order.

For 1..9 you generate either 9 or 18 palindromes depending upon whether you consider 1 digit numbers palindromic.

For 10..99 you generate 90 even digit and 90 odd digit palindromes.

For 100..999 you generate 900 even digit and 900 odd digit palindromes.

You have just generated all 1989 (or 1997 if including single digit numbers) of the palindromic numbers less than 1 million. There are 78,498 primes less than 1 million

Any algorithm that is based on generating primes then testing for a palindrome will be much slower that generating palindromes and then testing for primes

Comment: And note that you can automatically exclude any number that starts or ends with an even number, since it won't be prime. That makes it even sparser.

Comment: Also, even length palindromes are all multiples of 11, so, other than 11 itself, we can skip them all since they won't be prime.

Comment: @Blckknght I didn't know that! Do you have a reference?

Comment: @MarkRansom read the [second paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_prime)

Comment: Proof of even digit palindromes being divisibile by 11 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697096/prove-that-any-palindrome-with-an-even-number-of-digits-is-divisible-by-11

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on [byron he's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25299968/1405065) which adds several optimizations:

1. We can eliminate all even `x` values (other than 2) before doing any elaborate tests, since we can trivially tell they are not prime.
2. A small improvement is to only call `str(x)` once, and reuse the value later.
3. We can take advantage of the fact that all even-length palindromes are multiples of 11, which means that (except for 11 itself) they're not prime. We can jump ahead to the next odd-length `x` value.
4. Since we've already eliminated even numbers, our prime test only needs to test odd divisors. Further we can stop our loop when we reach `sqrt(x)`, rather than going all the way to `x` itself.
5. Finally, there's no need to use a Boolean flag variable to carry the primeness out of the loop. If we don't `break`, the `else` block attached to the loop will be run.

The code:

```
import math

def next_prime_palindrome(x):
    while True:
        x += 1

        if x > 2 and x % 2 == 0:        # even numbers greater than 2 are non-prime
            continue

        s = str(x)                      # compute str(x) just once
        if x > 11 and len(s) % 2 == 0:  # all even-length palindromes are multiples of 11
            x = 10 ** len(s)            # so jump to the next odd-length integer
            continue

        if s != s[::-1]:                # palindrome test
            continue

        for i in xrange(3, round(math.sqrt(x))+1, 2): # loop over odd potential divisors
            if x % i == 0:              # prime test
                break
        else: # this else block runs only if no break happened in the loop, so x is prime
            return x
```

Here are some tests runs, showing a few cases where the optimizations save significant time:

```
>>> next_prime_palindrome(1)
2
>>> next_prime_palindrome(3)
5
>>> next_prime_palindrome(9)
11
>>> next_prime_palindrome(11)
101
>>> next_prime_palindrome(99999)
1003001
>>> next_prime_palindrome(999999999)
10000500001
```

A further improvement might be to directly generate palindromes, rather than working with integers to start with, and doing a palindrome test to filter them. That would get quite a bit further from your original design, so I'll leave that for someone else.

Comment: If you're optimizing the code, you should remove the first "if": `if x > 2 and x % 2 == 0` - this condition will be `True` one time at most vs. the condition-check that'll happen every time. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
def golf(number):
    primes = []
    i = 2
    while i <= number:
        if isPrime(i, primes):
            primes.append(i)
        i += 1

    answer = primes[-1] + 1
    while True:
        if isPrime(answer, primes):
            primes.append(answer)
        if str(answer) == str(answer)[::-1]:
            return answer
        answer += 1

def isPrime(n, primes):
    for (p for p in primes if p<=n**0.5):
        if n%p == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

improved according to Blckknght's advice, thanks.

```
def golf(number):
    x = number 
    while True:
        x += 1
        if str(x) != str(x)[::-1]:
            continue
        for i in xrange(2, x):
            if x % i == 0 :
                break
        else:
            return x
```

Comment: As I commented on alfasin's answer, you can get rid of your the `is_prime` flag and use an `else` clause on the `for` loop to detect when the loop runs to completion without a `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution can be slightly modified in order to create an iterative solution:

```
def golf(number):
    x = number + 1
    while True:     
        is_golf = True
        for i in range(2, x):
            if x % i == 0 or str(x) != str(x)[::-1]:
                is_golf = False
                break

        if is_golf:
            return x
        x += 1
```

Comment: Rather than messing around with the `is_golf` flag variable, you can use an `else` clause below the `for` loop. An `else` there will only be run if the loop runs to completion without a `break` statement being hit.

Comment: @Blckknght I don't follow, please submit your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: OK, I've written [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25301594/1405065), with the improvement I was suggesting, plus several other optimizations.