# While loops with multiple condtions. Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that, given a random int, will return the next int that is both a prime number and a palindrome. i.e getint(13) will return 101.
One of the conditions of this function is that recursion is not allowed.

Where am i going wrong here?

```
def golf(number):
    x = number +1
    for i in range(2, x):
        while str(x) != str(x)[::-1] and  x % i == 0:
            x += 1
    return x
```

Comment: Your loops don't make any sense. `print x, i` inside the loop to see what's happening. Simplify the logic - if `x` is a palindrome, *then* check if it's prime. Maybe break out a separate `is_prime` function?

Comment: Aren't you sort of duplicating yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299837/given-and-integer-return-the-next-integer-that-is-a-prime-number-and-a-palindro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the problem into smaller pieces. It will be easier for you to understand what's going on:

```
def golf(number):
    x = number + 1
    while True:
        if is_palindrome(x) and is_prime(x):
            return x
        x += 1
```

Now all you have to do is implement `is_palindrome(x)` and `is_prime(x)`:

```
import math

def is_prime(x):
    for i in xrange(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(x))+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def is_palindrome(x):
    x = str(x)
    return x == x[::-1]
```

*Side note*: the `math.ceil(math.sqrt(x))+1` might be an overkill (perhaps `int(...)+1` is enough) if `math.sqrt` works correctly for squares (i.e. does not depend on floating point calculations so `math.sqrt(a*a)==a` is always true). Well in worst case the loop will do one more iteration then necessary. Better safe then sorry.

Comment: I don't think `+1` is necessary here: `int(math.sqrt(x))+1`-`math.ceil` would be enough.

Comment: No, it's not. `math.ceil(10) == 10`, `10 + 1 == 11`. Yes, that doesn't matter that much, so just saying.

Comment: @mikhail Yeah, I've just realized. Fixed it.

Comment: @mikhail Actually you need `int(...)+1` (I was too hasty). For example for `x==9` in your case it would be `xrange(2, 3)` which is `[2]`. You need `xrange(2, 4)` in order to check that `3` divides `9`.

Comment: Oh, right, you have a `range` there.. I got used to c++ for-loop, where you can make stop conditions with `<=`, which is quite useful.

Comment: And, actually, just +1 isn't correct either this time! If due to the limited precision of floating point calculation you get, for example, `math.sqrt(9) == 2.999999`, your range would be still [2], as `int(2.99999) + 1 == 3`. the correct version would be to combine the approaches: `math.ceil(math.sqrt(x))+1`.

Comment: @mikhail Well, that wouldn't change much, since then if a number is not a square you would do one unnecessary step at the end. For example for `6` you would have `<=3` and checking `3` is unnecessary (since it is above the square root).

Comment: @mikhail Well, I assume that `math.sqrt` works correctly for squares and it does not depend on floating point calculations. But if I'm wrong then I agree that the mix is necessary.

Comment: It sort of doesn't, at least, not if you accidentally cast your number to `float`: `a = float(10**300); b = math.sqrt(a); print a - b**2` gives 1.48701690848e+284.

Comment: @mikhail Actually the problem here is with `b**2` since you are multiplying two floats. You are looking at a slightly different problem. Because you are looking at `sqrt(a)**2` while I was talking about `sqrt(a**2)`. While mathematically equivalent these don't produce the same results on a computer. Note that for `a = float(10**150)` `math.sqrt(a*a) - a` is still `0`. Unfortunately I don't know the details of `math.sqrt` implementation which seems to be very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop will only go as far as `x`'s initial value: the `range(2,x)` is computed only once, right after `x = number + 1`. So increasing `x` *inside* the loop doesn't make a difference. Consider using a `while` loop, something like:

```
i = 2
while i <= x:
    ...
    i += 1
```

And you should probably first check is `x` is a palindrome (a "cheap" operation) and then, if it is, check weather it is prime (an "expensive" operation), not try do it all in a couple of nested loops that make little sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
def golf(number):
    x = number +1
    for i in range(2, x):
        while str(x) != str(x)[::-1] and  x % i == 0:
            x += 1
    return x
```

The program execution will not satisfy the `while` loop half of the time since any even number will not be divisible by any odd number and *vice-versa*. Also in a single iteration of the `for` loop, `x` will be incremented every time the `while` loop is satisfied.

You need to separate the prime checking and palindrome checking. The approach given by freakish is the simplest.